# Downloading PDF files from a remote website

Tags: linux, pdf, scripting, downloading-website-files

How can I download all the PDF files present in a website? Here I don't want to use wget command as that makes it manual and a lot time taking.

Comment: Have you considered about curl command?
Refer How to download multiple files using curl
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/download-a-file-with-curl-on-linux-unix-command-line/

Comment: Both Curl and wget can be utilized to download files by FTP and HTTP(s). You can send HTTP post request by curl and wget. Meanwhile curl provides APIs which can be used by programmers inside their own code. curl utilize libcurl which is a cross-platform library. Where wget is a command-line tool without any APIs. Curl supports more protocols that wget does not support. For example: RTSP, RTMP, SFTP, TFTP,SCP, TELNET, LDAP(S), IMAP, SMTP,POP3and FILE. while curl doesn’t supports recursive download but wget does.